# How can I concentrate out parameters entering linearly in a partially non-linear regression?

Tags: estimation, optimization, nonlinear-regression

I have model
$$y_i = x_i^\top\beta + \delta \exp(w_i\eta) + \epsilon_i$$
in setting up a non-linear regression problem

$$\min_{\beta,\delta,\eta} \frac{1}{2N} \sum_i^N (y_i - x_i^\top\beta - \delta \exp(w_i\eta))^2$$

I would prefer to concentrate out $\beta$. I there an easy way to do this?

By concentrating out I mean the following: Given an objective function $$\min_{\theta_1,\theta_2} f(\theta_1,\theta_2)$$ 
I assume that for a given $\theta_1$ there is a unique solution to $\min_{\theta_2} f(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and define this as $\theta_2(\theta_1)$ and back insert it in the original problem to get the problem

$$\min_{\theta_1} f(\theta_1,\theta_2(\theta_1))$$.

In the problem at hand my hunch is that I can let $\theta_1 = (\delta,\eta)$ then I can calcute $y_i - \delta \exp(\eta w_i)$ and regress that on $x_i$'s to get $\beta$.

So stacking i-terms the sum of squares is

$$(y - X\beta - \delta \exp(w \eta))^\top(y - X\beta - \delta \exp(w \eta))$$

where $\exp()$ applied to vector $w=(w_1,...,w_N)^\top$ is the $N \times 1$ vector of terms $\exp(w_i\eta)$.

The solution for $\beta$ would be $$(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top(y - \delta \exp(w \eta))$$ and so back inserting this I get

$$\epsilon = (y - \delta \exp(w \eta) - X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top(y - \delta \exp(w \eta)))\\[8pt]
= (I_N - X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top) [y - \delta \exp(w \eta)]$$
hence residuals as a function of $\delta,\eta$ when concentration out $\beta$ are simple the residuals from the regression $y - \delta \exp(w\eta) = X\beta + \epsilon$

This is how far I have gotten, but I am not sure the logic is sound?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you mean by "concentrate out" a parameter in a model?

Comment: I have edited stating what I mean by concentrating out and have written what I have gotten so far by applying the approach.

Comment: Thank you.  The logic is fine, but the implementation can be improved by noticing that the model is linear in $\delta.$ Thus, to solve this problem you need only search over values of $\eta:$ for each one you can obtain estimates of $\beta$ and $\delta$ using least squares.

Comment: True, I tried applying that logic. However the $\exp(w_i\eta)$ becomes part of the $(X^\top X)^{-1}$ matrix and as far as I can see that greatly complicates calculating the derivatives of the objective function $f(\beta(\eta),\delta(\eta),\eta)$ with respect to $\eta$. Since the purpose is numerical optimization I would like to keep these derivatives simple. Maybe I have missed something or does that make sense?

Comment: In almost any case, reducing a two-dimensional problem to a one-dimensional problem is an appreciable simplification.

Comment: In this case the non-linear part is very much more complex than here illustrated because it depends on calculating some spatial weight matrix that depends on $\eta$ so I would like to prevent the numerical solver from trying to compute numerical gradients. But are you saying that you think I can igore the change in the objective function that is indirect through $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta}\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \eta}$ and same through $\delta$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  However, by reducing the problem to one that is a search for a minimum SSR as a function of $\eta,$ you can apply the very best one-dimensional algorithms for minimizing functions that are expensive to evaluate.

Comment: point taken, thx for the valuable input. If you state you're suggestion as an answer I will accept it and question can be closed.